# How to show checkbox at the first column of gridview on mousehover

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview

I think every one was aware of `chrome browser` in this if we select `History` we will get all the browsing data. When we hover the mouse on a particular row a `check box` was visible and when we select that the button was enabled how to do this type of scenario

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Set the checkbox to display:none and then try this

```
protected void RecordsGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
            {
                if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
                {

                    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseover","checkbox.style.display='block'");
                    e.Row.Attributes.Add("onmouseout", "checkbox.style.display='none'");
                }
            }
```

Comment: Can I ask, is this possible in Win form`s DataGridView as well? I mean something like it?  I think I can do this, but in a loong way, with events (mousehover, mouseEnter, mouseLeave)

Comment: @MitjaBonca , I dont know , no idea about Win forms , haven't tried it.

Comment: @MitjaBonca , you will have to tweak around , I think it could be achieved.But having said that I have very little experience when it coms to win forms

Comment: Thx. I have removed my comment (it really was inappropriate, sorry for it). And about DGV n win forms... I am sure its possible, but not in any short way, I will try to do, but it sure will be a pain in my a**. thx anyway

Comment: @MitjaBonca its ok , but remember that next time.All the best for your experiment, try researching that , it wont be a tedious task I think.

Answer (score 0):

@User:  Hi you can make check box visible using j query for that follow folowing link in which it highlight row, but using same funda you can make check box visible and button also.

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=250

http://jquerybyexample.blogspot.com/2011/06/highlight-row-on-mouseover-in-gridview.html

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
   $(function(){
            $("#gridviewname tr").live("hover",function(){
                 $(this).find("input[id*='chkName']").show();
            },
            function(){
                 $(this).find("input[id*='chkName']").hide();
            });

            $("#gridviewname tr").live("click",function(){
                 if($(this).find("input[id*='chkName']").attr("checked"))
                 {
                       $(this).find("input[id*='chkName']").removeAttr("checked");
                       $(this).find("input[id*='chkName']").hide();
                 }
                 else
                 {
                       $(this).find("input[id*='chkName']").attr("checked",true);
                       $(this).find("input[id*='chkName']").show();
                 }
            });

         });
```